# Оборот "кроме нас" -- запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Я знаком с рекомендациями и Лопатина и Розенталя и прочитал ответы на другие похожие вопросы, но смутное спинномозговое чувство мешает мне механически применить описанные там правила к следующему предложению:

> Но поскольку кроме нас, в барак ещё никого не поселили, ...

Следует ли выделять **`кроме наc`** запятыми с двух сторон, или тут не стоит выделять его вообще? Совсем без запятых, как было у автора, выглядит на мой взгляд не совсем грамотно, сомнительно выглядит и вариант с одной запятой, а вариант с запятыми с двух сторон кажется мне несколько неуклюжим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае желательно не обособлять оборот: *Но поскольку **кроме нас** (за исключением нас) в барак ещё никого не поселили...*

**Пояснение**

1. Этот оборот имеет значение **исключения** (надо иметь в виду, что он может иметь еще и значение **включения**).

(1) ‘за исключением кого-чего-либо’, ‘не считая кого-чего-либо’: *Дом, кроме этой комнаты, стоял заколоченный* (А. Т.); *Все улыбнулись, кроме лейтенанта* (Каз.);

(2) ‘сверх кого-чего-либо’, ‘вдобавок к кому-чему-либо’: *Кроме старика, в этот день приходило к нам ещё двое* (Ч.).

По Розенталю обороты обоих видов **обычно обособляются,** за исключением малораспространенных вариантов, например:

Значение ВКЛЮЧЕНИЯ: *Кроме зарплаты они получают и премиальные. Кроме рисунков  были приложены ещё чертежи. Кроме хозяев в комнате были и гости. Кроме вашей химии существуют ведь и другие науки.*

Надо отметить, что обороты со значением ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ **обособляются чаще**, так как исключение желательно подчеркнуть, но вот нашелся пример необособленного оборота: *Я встаю из-за стола. Кроме меня тут дверь открыть некому* (интонация простого предложения без обособления).

2. **Как объяснить нежелательность обособления** оборота в приведенном примере:

*Но поскольку **кроме нас** в барак ещё никого не поселИли...*

Здесь надо учитывать, что это придаточное предложение в сложноподчиненном предложении, поэтому общая расстановка ударений в СПП **не позволяет обособить этот оборот** (то есть дополнительно выделить его паузами и ударением).

Пример другого необособленного оборота со значением исключения (= не считая нас, исключая нас) **в распространенном предложении:**

Пример: *Затем мы оказались в комнате свиданий. **Кроме нас**  там было шестеро посетИтелей, заключённых отделял стеклянный барьЕр.* [Сергей Довлатов. Наши (1983)]

Comment: Sharon, здравствуйте! Надо бы переделать ответ, ведь оборот с *кроме* из вопроса имеет значение исключения. А вот запятые всё равно ставить не хочется, видимо потому, что прерывистое чтение здесь не очень подходит.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
  Спасибо, Александр.  Ответ я переделала полностью, он показался мне не очень удачным,  да и времени уже прошло немало, как-то всё мыслится по-другому. Если вас не затруднит, то проверьте, пожалуйста, текст .

Comment: Последний пример не подходит - там включение.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Я внимательно отнеслась к этому примеру, и вот что думаю.  Итак, в приемной шестеро посетителей. Мы входим в это число? Если не входим, то это исключение, а если вместе с нами шесть, то включение. Как вы это определяете?

Comment: Какое же это коварное *кроме*! Вы меня запутали... Чтобы всем всё было понятно, писали бы по-другому, добавили бы, например, *ещё*. Мне всё же видится такой смысл: *там были мы и ещё шестеро посетителей*.

Comment: Мне тоже так видится. Мы вошли, а там уже было шесть человек. Тогда это за исключением нас?

Comment: Нет, у меня это включение :). Как в примере со стариком: *к нам приходило еще двое* (вдобавок к старику).

Comment: Но в этом примере нет слова "еще".  К тому же в том предложении считают всех приходивших за день, а в этом примере – всех находившихся в комнате сейчас. Ну как бы очередь из шести человек пере вами.  Иных указаний нет, а трактовка может быть любая (возможно, контекст подсказывает, но его у нас нет).  Я вам еще не очень надоела, а то давайте оставим этот вопрос на собственное усмотрение. :)

Comment: Я определяю так. **Исключение**: никого не поселили, а нас поселили; все улыбнулись, а лейтенант нет; в небе никого не было, а чайки были. **Включение**: в комнате были гости, и мы тоже; там было шестеро посетителей, и мы вдобавок.Ну да ладно. Плюс вам!

Comment: А если так: Кроме нас, в комнате было еще шесть человек. И с нами тоже шесть? Какая-то виртуальная у вас математика, :)  Ну да ладно, пусть будет по-вашему, только я исправлять уж не буду, хорошо?

Comment: С ***еще*** становится намного понятнее. Всего восемь получается. И запятую я бы не стал ставить: мне больше нравится разграничивать эти включения-исключения.

Comment: Запятые – это не способ однозначно определять семантику.  Лучше так:  если уж мы не обособляем исключающий оборот, то нужны дополнительные грамматические указания на значение исключения  (в виде наречия, например).

Comment: Ладно, заканчиваем. Видимо, в этом примере сбивает числительное. Но у меня смысл исключения здесь никак не проходит. Написали бы "не считая нас", и всё. А так получается, что шестеро были, а мы нет, но ведь это не так (и я там был, мёд-пиво пил...).

Comment: Может быть, может быть... Но ведь это художественный текст, а не только упражнение по пунктуации...