# Ты знаешь какой-либо язык(,) кроме русского?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Ты знаешь какой-либо язык(,) кроме русского?

Comment: Запятую лучше поставить.

Comment: А еще лучше обозначить тему и предложить свое решение, которое мы здесь обсудим.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Оборот "кроме нас" -- запятые](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458022/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5)